# Django form : Set class when initializing the form

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

There's something I don't understand with Django. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to add the class 'form-control' to each of my CharField / URLField. What I did is, in the `__init__`

```
for key,item in self.fields.items():
        print(key)
        if item.__class__.__name__ in ['ChoiceField','URLField']:
            item.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

I checked many times if the target was a good one and it was. However, the class doesn't applied ... And when I tried :

```
self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

It worked ! Does someone knows who the first loop doesn't worked ? Do I have to 'save' the widget or something ? Thanks !

Comment: Do you call super anywhere in that \_\_init__ method?

Comment: have you tried to do `self.fields[key].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'` in your for loop?

Comment: DavidM : Yes, I'm calling super at the beginning of the __init__
AlexanderLarikov : I also tried it and it doesn't worked

The thing is that just a part of the fields are affected, not all of the CharField / URLField

Comment: What do you get with a print item.__class__.__name__ in the loop?

Comment: I have all of my listed fields. I don't know why but when I changed the position of this loop (I set it before all of the changes about the fields instead of after) it worked ...

Comment: I think it could be interesting to know why. If you edit your question to include the rest of the code, maybe we can figure it out.